# Spring CrudRepository select all groups with a parent from the list

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Group extends Auditable<String> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Long id;

  private String parentGuid;

  // other fields
  // getters/setters

}
```

With the repository defined as follows:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface GroupRepository extends CrudRepository<Group, String> {

  Group findById(String id);

}
```

I'm trying to get all groups that have a parentGuid equal to any one of a list of guids. So if I have a list like so - `List<String> listGuid = ['parent1', 'parent2', 'parent3']`, I want my sql query to be like this:

```
select * from groups where parentGuid='parent1' or parentGuid='parent2' or parentGuid='parent3';
```

So in the repository class, I want to have a method like this which automatically constructs that query using the list of guids passed in:

```
List<Group> findByGroupParentGuidIn(List<String> guids);
```

But I get a warning saying 'Cannot resolve property GroupParentGuid' and I don't think is the right way to construct that query. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Use `findByParentGuidIn` instead of `findByGroupParentGuidIn`. After findBy it will use the property name you want to filter. In your case, you added class as well.

```
List<Group> findByParentGuidIn(List<String> guids);
```

Comment: For reference: [Spring Data JPA - Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)